# VUE striking 2 times console.log

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I got a problem with console.log in my script>methods>console.log

I dont understand, why I sending 2 times request when I got only 1 time write console.log.

I tried to delete methods and move under data>return... still work but still twice.

```
// ....
// ...
<form
      @submit.prevent="getLogin"
      id="form"
      <div class="mb-4">
        <input
          name="text"
          type="text"
          placeholder="1547089"
          v-model="loginForm.text"
          id="order-id"
          required
          minlength="5"
          />
      </div>
    <div>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="****"
          v-model="loginForm.password"
          required
          minlength="4"
          maxlength="4"/>
    </div>
        <div
          id="div-submit">
            <button
              type="submit"
              v-on:click="getLogin"
              v-bind:disabled="loginForm.password.length < 4"
              id="submit">
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loginForm:{
        text: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLogin(){
      console.log("Posielam do konzole", this.loginForm)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you omit a few things? What I see there is no `<template></template>` wrapper in your HTML, so I assume this is just rendered as plain HTML and thus all the Vue attributes are ignored and the `getLogin()` just gets executed.

Comment: this is not a full code